# How does simple fixed-point conversion work?

Tags: c++, math, fixed-point

I think I understand what happens when converting values to fixed point representation by using the following code. Use 2bit for integer part and 30bit for number's fractional part, so we get an resulting range `-2.0` up to `1.999999999`

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int transformForTransfer(double value){
    int integer;
    unsigned int shiftedInteger;
    double fraction;
    if(value >= 0){
        integer = (int32_t)value;
        fraction = value - integer;
        shiftedInteger = (unsigned int)(integer << 30);
    }
    else{
        integer = -2;
        fraction = 2.0 + value;
        shiftedInteger = 0x80000000;
    }

    auto fractionPart = (unsigned int)round(fraction * std::pow(2, 30));
    std::cout << "fraction part          : " << std::bitset<sizeof(fractionPart) * 8>(fractionPart) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "integer part           : " << std::bitset<sizeof(integer) * 8>(integer) << std::endl;
    auto result = (shiftedInteger | fractionPart);
    auto bits = std::bitset<sizeof(result) * 8>(result).to_string();
    std::cout << "value bits unsigned int: " << bits << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

But why does using this simple approach:

```
unsigned int doubleToTransfer(double value)
{
    return (unsigned int)(round(value * std::pow(2, 30)));
}
```

lead to the exact same result:

```
int demoInt = -2000000000;
double demo;
while (demoInt < 1999999999){
    demoInt += 1;
    demo = demoInt * 1E-09;
    if(transformForTransfer(demo) != doubleToTransfer(demo)){
        // never reached
        std::cout << " != " << demo << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand the question. You want to know why the first version has to be rather complicated when it can be done in a simpler way? Having one example where both yield the same result doesn't mean that they are equivalent

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, that is the question. I added demo code to the question to show, that both ways show the same results for the value range ```-2.0``` up to ```1.999999999```